# A letter from, or a letter by?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I am not a native speaker and am wondering what the difference is, if any, between "from" and "by" in the context of a letter, as set out below.

I think that a letter "from" may indicate the letter comes from a certain place, e.g. "A letter from Spain".

A letter can also come *from* someone. A letter can also be *by* someone, correct?

Thus, which one (or both) of the below would be correct?

- A letter from Patrick; or
- A letter by Patrick?

Comment: We usually use *from* with things that we receive - if you say *I got a letter from Patrick*, we understand that Patrick wrote the letter as well as sending it. In other situations we use *by* to identify the person who created something. The something could be a letter - e.g. *we know from a letter written by Mozart's mother that...* If you use *by* on its own it suggests you are talking about a work of art - *a painting by Caravaggio*, *a novel by Dostoyevsky* etc. For everyday things we usually include the verb - *a letter written by Patrick*, *an apartment block built by XYZ* etc.

Comment: _A letter from X_ is the normal expression. You might possibly use _by_ if you were considering a letter as a work of literature, but not in everyday conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a letter my be **from**: 1. a person; 2. a company, hospital, etc.; 3. a specific place (from London; Germany; etc.) and **to** 1. a person; 2. an isnstitution (financial, economic, etc.).
*I received a latter from the Pope.* denotes that I was the addressee, whereas
*I received a letter by the Pope.* suggests that I am not a person the Pope wrote to.